# Searching in linked list with scanner in java

Tags: java, search, linked-list, nodes

I want to search in linked list with scanner but i cannot do it. I can search without scanner. What is wrong with this code?

My search method:

```
    public void Search(Object data){
    Node tmp = head ;
    while(tmp != null ){

        if(tmp.getData() == data){
            System.out.println("Your input is in the list");
        }

            tmp = tmp.getNext();


    }

}
```

And my main class:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    LinkedList list =new Linkedlist();
    ...... // adding methods etc.
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your input: ");
    String x=input.next();
    list.Search(x);
}
```

Comment: can you describe the error?

Comment: I write input as data which is in the list but it didn't match. Code doesn't give me an error but it does't work correctly.

Comment: @mancini13 "it doesn't work" is completely useless as a description for what's wrong.  What doesn't work? How does it not work? "it didn't match" is closer, but you haven't included what you got, nor what you expected to get.

Comment: I expect that my input match with node's data. I cannot expect anything else from search method.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the `String` parameter into `search(data)`, which is being cast as an `Object`.

You will need to either type-cast the `Object data` parameter to type `String`, or change the method signature to explicitly accept type `String`

Comment: Yes, i tried all this things but anything did't change.

Comment: I would recommend running in a debugger with breakpoints to see exactly what is happening. I.e. exception, false negative find, etc.
Without that, it will be difficult for anyone to assist further

Comment: I did it too. Codes doesn't enter in if condition with scanner but when i use something like list.Search("input") it work correctly.

Comment: In that case, I would recommend editting your original question with a more complete versrion of code so others can build and help you debug

Comment: I solved my problem. I implement head node as a null in constructor that is why it give me an error with equal method.

Answer (score 1):

To build on what Adam has suggested, you can consider the following code:

```
public void Search(String data){

     Node tmp = head ;
     while(tmp != null ){

         if(tmp.getData().equalsIgnoreCase(data)){
             System.out.println("Your input is in the list");
         }

            tmp = tmp.getNext();
     }   
}
```

You should use .equals() or .equalsIgnoreCase() to compare the string instead of comparing by == which compares each other as objects.

[What is the difference between == vs equals() in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/what-is-the-difference-between-vs-equals-in-java)

Comment: can you post the logs in your question? i guess, nullpointer might be a different problem